# Wrong encoding in unit test output

Tags: android-studio, character-encoding, testng

In Android Studio 1.4 on Windows 10, I am using TestNG to write unit tests for my app.

When I run my unit test, the output window shows this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :Ê¼Ä�aluÅ«
Actual   :Ê¾Ä�aluÅ«
```

I have already changed every encoding setting to UTF-8 and also added `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the Java command line. But still the output of the command is read back in as ISO-8859-1.

What can I do to get the correct output from the unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration.

I just created a file `studio64.exe.vmoptions` in the correct folder and added this line:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```